# Как оптимальнее распарсить kml координаты в PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите как наиболее оптимально можно распарсить строку такого вида

```
    35.101318359375,53.994853965628,0
    34.595947265625,53.366942995161,0
    37.15576171875,52.459356636837,0
    37.41943359375,53.748710796899,0
    36.815185546875,53.865485508421,0
    35.974731445312,54.027133444125,0
    35.57373046875,54.204223304732,0
    35.211181640625,54.088395486699,0
```

мой код отвратителен, а больше всего я переживаю за то, что пока не могу его улучшить.

```
while (strripos($value, ","))
{
    $lon = floatval(stristr($value, ',', true));
    $value = stristr($value, ',');

    $value = mb_substr($value,1);


    $lat = floatval(stristr($value, ',', true));
    $value = stristr($value, ',');

    $value = mb_substr($value,1);

    substr($value,0);

    $alt = floatval(stristr($value, ' ', true));
    $value = stristr($value, ' ');

    echo $lat . " | " . $lon . " | " . $alt . "<br>";
}
```

Где $value вышеописанная строка.

Comment: ознакомьтесь с `explode`, решение будет в 3 строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные в виде строки, то используйте `explode()` для разеделения ее по символу `\n` (конец строки), если это содержимое файла, используйте `file()` для считывания его по строкам в массив.

Далее используйте все тот же `explode` для разделения значений, в данном случае по символу `,` (запятой).

```
$str = "......" ; // ваша строка

foreach(explode("\n", $str) as $line){
    list($lat, $lon, $alt) = explode(',', trim($line)); 
    // [$lat, $lon, $alt] = ...;  для свежих версий пхп
    // echo ....
}
```

Comment: `$temp = explode ("\n", $value);

    foreach ($temp as &$str){
        $tmp_coord = explode (",", $str);
        $lng = floatval($tmp_coord[0]);
        $lat = floatval($tmp_coord[1]);
        $alt = floatval($tmp_coord[2]);


        if (count($tmp_coord) == 3){
            echo $lat . " " . $lng . " " . $alt . "<br>";
        }
    }`

Сделал так с вашей подсказки